Cannot connect to remote postgress that runs in docker
I have AWS ec2 instance that runs docker compose:
version: '3.8'
services:
  prod-db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
    volumes:
      - production_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./script.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_script.sql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
volumes:
  production_data:

And i want to connect to this postgress from remote machine.
I have ensured that the postgres config allows remote connection with:
docker exec -it prod-db bash
echo "listen_addresses = '*'" >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
echo "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5" >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
docker compose restart prod-db

However i am still unable to connect to postgress from my local machine.
Local connection from ec2 instance works. And configuration should be correct, so where is the catch?
I am using my public ipv4 address of my ec2 instance for connectiction, so for jdbs it looks like
jdbc:postgresql://<public ipv4 address of my ec2 instance>:5432/<database name>

The database is created by script.sql, and everything is correctly created.
Why is this happening? Did i forget some postgres config or some aws ec2 config? Afaik the port 5432 should be public on ec2.

"i am still unable to connect to postgress from my local machine." it sounds like you're getting some sort of error message that you excluded from the question?

Did you open the port in the security group attached to the EC2 instance?

Did you use netstat or ss to confirm the listen address on the EC2 host?

You need to be more explicit on what error you get when you try that ?
